# How to rewrite query in IIS 7

Tags: html, iis, url-rewriting, iis-7

I want to rewrite this URL

https://www.website.com/parameter-1?query=100345046

To this

https://www.website.com/parameter?query=100345046

---

Basically I want the **-1** removed from the URL.

I made an example which works, using [**RegExr**](https://regexr.com/4tqk4), but I don't know how to implement this using the IIS.

So far I made this rule but I can't get the query part after the `-1` to stick the to rewrote URL.

```
<rule name="Redirect" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/parameter-1$" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/parameter" appendQueryString="true" />
</rule>
```

Comment: Maybe you could alter the URL in place where you make request? JS maybe?

Comment: @MichałTurczyn The problem is that it a copy of a page was indexed by Google and I'm trying to redirect the "dev" page to the regular one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright I figured it out.

```
<rule name="Redirect" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="/parameter-1\?query=(.*)$" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/parameter?" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```